# How to add currentTime in access DB?

Tags: java, database, date

I have a database in access, I have a field `Date`, with type Date/time. All right.

I need to add in field date, current date from Java (Netbeans)
I tried some other opinions but nothing works.

How to add currentTime in access DB?

Comment: Try to work it out from a command line app. first. Then you should be able to implement the solution in a Swing app. General tip: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Always **search Stack Overflow** before posting. Inserting a date value into a SQL database via JDBC 4.2 and later using `LocalDate` class with `ZoneId` has been addressed many many times already.

Comment: Which means are you using for accessing Access from Java? JDBC, UCanAccess, JPA, Hibernate, …? Would a solution in SQL alone be acceptable? Also please spell out what you tried and how it failed so we can see if and how it can and should be corrected.